# Change Properties of Items using a forEach Method (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I'm using a javascript forEach method to iterate over items in an array, but it's throwing an error when I try and do something with the items.

In the code below when I console log 'item' it gives the desired behavior of logging 'div1, div2, div3' to the console.  However, when I try and make a change to these items it won't allow it.  The examples of using a forEach method in JS when you Google it is very abstract.

How do I use this method to change the background colors or other properties of the items?

Codepen link is here https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/boJBKB

JS

```
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
var div3 = document.getElementById('div3');

var myArray = ['div1','div2','div3']

myArray.forEach(function(item){

  console.log(item);

  item.style.backgroundColor = "blue";  

})
```

CSS

```
.div {height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: red; margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="div" id="div1"></div>
<div class="div" id="div2"></div>
<div class="div" id="div3"></div>
```

Any help would be awesome

Emily

Comment: That array is an array of strings, not an array of those variables

Comment: Replace the strings `'div1'` etc. with Pointers `div1`

Comment: Thank you Patrick and Jonas.  That did work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotes like: `var myArray = [div1,div2,div3]`

Answer (score 0):

your `myArray` contains `Strings`, not `Dom Nodes`.
try this code:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
var div3 = document.getElementById('div3');

var myArray = [div1,div2,div3]

myArray.forEach(function(item){
  console.log(item);
  item.style.backgroundColor = "blue";  
})
```